# Azure Bicep ( key vault secret passing as a parameter to local variable)

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am new to Azure Bicep.I am trying to use the key vault secret name and value for the virtual machine (Window) credential. But I am facing a problem with passing the name and value of the key vault as a parameter to a local variable. Anyone who can guide me regarding this matter?

```
@description('Password for the Virtual Machine.')
@secure()
param adminPassword string = keyVault.getSecret()
```

Comment: Is this helpful? [How to retrieve keyvault secret in a module bicep](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/5507#discussioncomment-1863758)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `getSecret()` function in the `main.bicep` file (i.e. as a defaultValue) - you can only use that in a module within a bicep file. @Deep has a link for that...

If you want to pass the secret to `main.bicep` you need to use a parameter reference in a parameter file, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-key-vault#edit-the-parameters-file